# django url matching failure for the coltrane tutorial

Tags: python, django

Noob question to be sure. I am working on the coltrane project from Practical Django Projects, Second Edition.

My urlpattern entry is:

```
(r'^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'coltrane.views.entry_detail'),
```

The actual URL is: 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2012/sep/17/thank-you-very-much

The actual URL does not trigger the view - 'coltrane.views.entry_detail' - that is associated with the urlpattern entry. Instead, it triggers the catchall pattern at the end of the url pattern tuple. The catchall pattern is:

```
(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

When the browser tries to load the page, manage.py reports: [18/Sep/2012 10:59:31] "GET /blog/2012/sep/17/thank-you-very-much HTTP/1.1" 404 1667

The debugging page reports Page not found, No FlatPage matches the given query.

As far as I can figure, everything is in order. So what is my simple, NOOB mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to append the slash at the end of your url because your regex defines that a slash should be matched at the end of the url (`/$`)

So change it to:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2012/sep/17/thank-you-very-much/
```

Answer (score 2):

Change "P?" to "?P" while catching slug field.
(P?[-\w]+) => (?P[-\w]+)

Comment: I corrected the typo. The problem still remains however. I the server and the browser to make sure.